# Data stored in localStorage isn't there when I redirect

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have Javascript on a page that sets localStorage data:
`localStorage.setItem('blah', 1);`

Then, I have code that will redirect to another page on a button click.

On the other page I try to access the item in localStorage, but I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'blah' of null` 30% of the time. How come localStorage isn't saving each time?

Am I missing something?

**On Current Page**

```
localStorage.setItem('blah', 1);
$('.btn').on('click', function() { window.location.href = 'http://example.com/signup?redirect=/chkout'; });
```

**On Redirect Page**

```
localStorage.getItem('blah', 1); ==> null
```

Comment: Show your code that saves in localStorage and reads it.

Comment: Try in Firebug, with a **Persist** on the error console - see if any helpful error messages come up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happen because

1. The tab/window is in incognito / private surfing mode
2. The browser is configured to track no history at all
3. The item was set on another port or scheme (of the same domain) (e.g. http://foo.com instead of https://foo.com)

[From the  W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute):

> 1. The user agent may throw a SecurityError exception and abort these steps instead of returning a Storage object if the request violates a policy decision (e.g. if the user agent is configured to not allow the page to persist data).
> 2. If the Document's origin is not a scheme/host/port tuple, then throw a SecurityError exception and abort these steps.

Comment: It ended up being due to http and https.

Answer (score 0):

The localStorage data should persist, by several documentations. There may be a case when your localStorage data gets overwritten by some other operation. You can try to debug this by adding following eventListener:

```
window.addEventListener("storage", function(data) {
   console.debug(data);
}, false);
```

This should log the data, every time the storage is accessed.